# if $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ how can we prove that $T\cdot T^t$ is $\geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

if $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ how can we prove that $T\cdot T^t$ equals zero or greater than zero?
[image]

Comment: Do you know what it means for a matrix to be positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $v^tT^tTv=(Tv)^t(Tv)=\|Tv\|^2\ge 0$.
$T^tT>0\iff v^tT^tTv>0,\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\iff \|Tv\|^2>0,\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\iff Tv\ne0,\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$
So, $T^tT>0$ if and only if $T$ is not singular if and only if $\det(T)\ne0$ .

Similarly,$TT^t>0$ if and only if $T^t$ is not singular if and only if $\det(T)=\det(T^t)\ne0$

Comment: Or in other words, $$v^tT^tTv=(Tv)^t(Tv)= dot \ product \ of \ Tv \ with \ itself =\|Tv\|^2\ge 0$$

Comment: T*T(transpose)≥0 or T(transpose)*T≥0 can we use that formula you give, for both?

Comment: Sure, for $TT^t$, we will end up with $\|T^tv\|^2$.

Comment: Girgin, how can you prove it?

Comment: Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $v^tTT^tv=v^t(T^t)^tT^tv=(T^tv)^t(T^tv)=\|T^tv\|^2\ge 0$.

Comment: For an easier way, you can say the following: We know $T^tT$ is positive for all $n\times n$ matrices $T$. As $T^t$ is also a $n\times n$ matrix, we conclude $(T^t)^tT^t$ is positive. Then, using the fact that $(T^t)^t=T$ we have $TT^t$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your concern.But it is asked in which conditions T(transpose)*T> 0and T*T(transpose)>0 . And the v you define is eigenvalue?

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: Mr. Girgin Thanks you so much for your helps.You used let v element of R. v means eigenvalue or eigenvector or a random capital?(so we can name it as whatever we want.)

Comment: It is an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 0):

As for strict positivity, we actually mean $v^tT^tTv=0$ only if $v=0$. This will be guaranteed iff $T$ is nonsingular, i.e. invertible, i.e. $det(T)\neq 0$.

Also, in case you ask, this helps us redefine a new inner-product on vectors in $R^n$. If you take any collection of linearly independent vectors in $R^n$ and "declare" them to be mutually orthogonal, it is equivalent to saying that "from now on, the inner product of given $v$ and $w$ vectors will be $<Tv,Tw>$ instead of $<v,w>$ which in fact corresponds to $T=1.$